# Comparing effective interest rate

Tags: finance

> You have 1000 that you want to deposit in a savings account. Bank A
> computes the amount value of your investment using the amount function
> $A_1(t) = 1+0.049t$ whereas Bank B uses the amount function $A_2(t) =
> > (1.4)^{12t}$. Where should you put your money?

Correct answer : B

I solved just by comparing effective interest rate for first period, $i_1 = \frac{A(1)-A(0)}{A(0)}$
but couldn't either one of them become larger depending on which period you choose? What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: Is $A_2(t)$ really equal to $(1.4)^{12t}$? That growth seems way too fast.

Comment: If $t$ is in years the first looks like 4.9% pa, based only on the original amount. But the second would be 40% per month compounding, which looks like a mistake. I would find it hard to trust the second option - if it looks too good to be true it probably is!

Comment: yup to the 12th power.